# Platform.OS within XML in React Native

Tags: android, xml, react-native, cross-platform

I just started working on React Native and have a component, where I need to add some specific XML when I'm on Android... I found the [Platform Specific Code](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/releases/0.26/docs/platform-specific-code.html) but I can't find an example of doing this within XML...

I want to do something similar to below, where I add in some extra view when it's on Android... I know that I can do a separate file for Android by doing the .android.js extension, but as it's a minor difference in the UI, I would prefer to keep everything in the same file...

```
<View style={styles.rowContainer}>
 Platform.select({
  android: {
   <Text>Test</Text>
  }
 }),
 <Button style={styles.notificationsItem}>Push Notifications</Button>
 <View style={styles.rightContainer}>
  <Image style={styles.thumbNotifications} source={notifications_checked} />
 </View>
```

So does anyone know how I would use Platform.OS in-between XML like above?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look at this code sample, it's pretty straightforward:

```
class TestComponent extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        {Platform.select({
          android: <Text>Test</Text>
        )}
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

When you want to put JS code in JSX, put codes in `{}`.
like:

`<View style={styles.rowContainer}>
      {Platform.select({
        android: {
          <Text>Test</Text>
        }
      })}
    <Button style={styles.notificationsItem}>Push Notifications</Button>
    <View style={styles.rightContainer}>
      <Image style={styles.thumbNotifications} source={notifications_checked} />`

Answer (score 0):

the simplest example will be blow

```
import { Platform, Text, View, TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native';

const ContactNumber = () => {
    return (
      <View>
        {Platform.select({
          android: (
            <Text>This is android</Text>
          ),
          ios: (
            <TouchableOpacity>
              <Text>This is IOS</Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
          ),
        })}
      </View>
    );
  };
```

i used `hooks`, same logic can be used in the `class component`.